# Click listview item and display image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

im trying to create a listview where if you press an item on that list, it displays an image in fullscreen. I have about 10 different items in the list and I want to display different images for each item.

I used this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

But instead of showing the name of my string item, i want it to show an image. How do i fix this?

I have been trying to check other questions, but they have been kinda hard to follow since im new to this.

Comment: you have to start a new Activity inside onItemClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have images in your drawable folder for all different items(in list view)
Change the single_list_item.xml to

```
single_list_item_view.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />    
</LinearLayout>
```

change your SingleListItem.java

```
  package com.androidhive.androidlistview;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

            ImageView productimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

            Intent i = getIntent();
            // getting attached intent data
            String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
            // displaying selected product name
            switch(product){
          case "item1":
              productimage.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
           break;
          case "item2":
              productimage.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image2);
          break;
          case "item3":
              productimage.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image3);
         break;
          .
          .
          .
          .
          .
//upto all 10 images

         }

        }
    }
```

Comment: There are some errors in this code. `setImageDrawable` takes a Drawable argument, not an integer id. It should be `setImageResource` instead. The switch statement also has incorrect syntax: `case:item1` should be `case item1:`. As well, Strings can only be used in switch statements in Java 7 and later, and the values in the cases must be constant literals.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i got it to work. Somehow i combined your ideas or something. Dont really know how i managed to fix it though. I tried both your methods individually at first and no one worked. Then i just messed around and got it to work! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing the item/text in SingleListItem class you could use the passed item to check which image should be displayed in an imageview. Something like that:

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

        // TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.someImage);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
        // displaying selected product name
        if (product.equals("item1")) {
            image.setDrawableResource(R.drawable.YOURIMAGE);
        } else if (product.equals("item2"))
            image.setDrawableResource(R.drawable.ANOTHERIMAGE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with only a few changes to the tutorial code.

First, in `single_list_item_view.xml`, you'll need to use an `ImageView` instead of a `TextView`, since you want to show an image. You can find documentation for image views, including what attributes they support, [on the Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Second, you'll need to change the line that looks up the `TextView` to find your new `ImageView` instead. This will only require changing the following line:

```
TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);
```

to:

```
// Assuming you gave your ImageView the id "product_image" in single_list_item_view.xml
ImageView productImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.product_image);
```

You'll need to add the images that you want to show into your project. The simplest place for these to go is in the `res/drawable` folder. The name of the image files will determine their "ids". For example, if you have `res/drawable/photoshop.png`, you can refer to it with the id `R.drawable.photoshop`.

Next you need to figure out which image to show in `SingleListItem`. The key part of how clicking on an item in the list shows something else is in `SingleListItem`:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
```

Correspondingly, in `AndroidListViewActivity`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
i.putExtra("product", product);
startActivity(i);
```

The `Intent` is how you send information from the list activity to the activity that shows the item. In this case, the information being sent is which item to show. You have a few options about how to do this part. One simple way is just to inspect the `product` string and choose the appropriate drawable:

```
int imageId = -1;
if (product.equals("Adobe After Effects")) {
  imageId = R.drawable.after_effects;
} else if (product.equals("Adobe Bridge")) {
  imageId = R.drawable.bridge;
} else if ...
  ... // All your other cases
}
```

This approach obviously doesn't scale very well, but it will work okay for your simple example. Another possible approach would be to pass the image id in the `Intent`, rather than the product name, for example:

```
// In AndroidListViewActivity:
i.putExtra("product", R.drawable.after_effects);

// In SingleListItem:
int imageId = i.getIntExtra("product", -1); 
// -1 in the call above is the value to return if "product" is not in the Intent
```

The final thing you need to do is set the `Drawable` for the `ImageView` you found earlier:

```
// Make sure to check that the id is valid before using it
if (imageId != -1) {
  Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(imageId);
  productImage.setDrawable(d);
}
```

`getResources()` fetches the `Resources` object for you application. You can use the `Resources` object to look up things like strings and drawables you've defined in your `res` folder. The tutorial you're following also uses it to look up an array of strings in the `res` folder. Again, you can see everything `Resources` supports on the [Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html).

Comment: why the line: "int imageId = -1;" above:    if (product.equals("Adobe After Effects")) {
  imageId = R.drawable.after_effects;
} else if (product.equals("Adobe Bridge")) {
  imageId = R.drawable.bridge;
} else if ...
  ... // All your other cases
}


It seems to generate an error for me